# C++: Using tree or map inside of a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, tree

I would like to store data in a tree format:

```
      A
      |
---------------------
|          |        |
B1         B2       ...
|          |
------     -------
|    |     |  |  |
C1   C2    C3 ...
```

A and B1, ...Bn and C1,...Cn are of the type `std::string`. It is not necessary that the elements are ordered (but wouldn't hurt either). The maximum depth of the tree is 3. The number of insert operations will most likely be the same as search operations. If I search I want to eleborate if the combination of string B1 with C1 als child is included in the tree (and possibly other combination of B's and C's).

I'm wondering if I should use a map inside of a map

```
std::map<std::string,std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> myTree;
```

for this purpose or if a tree (like [here](http://stlplus.sourceforge.net/stlplus3/docs/ntree.html)) would be better for the job. My first impression is, that it might would be easier to search inside of the map, because I have direct access to the keys. Referencing the mentioned tree implementation I would have to realise the "string" search on the tree by myself - fetching the childs as an array and iterate over these values (and then again over the childs of the found string). Will using a tree provide better performance or maintainability?

Comment: "if the combination of string B1 with C1 als child is included"  The way you phrased that makes me worry that the B level might not be unique.  Can the same string appear twice as Bi?  If not, your map of map of sets idea is simple and has decent performance, so no reason to look for a more difficult solution.

Comment: They should be unique. That means if a new B entry is added I will have to check wether or not it is already included an merge the C's accordingly. Otherwise I would have too much work searching for (the possible) multiple appearences of B and that stuff.